# if the link contains the word "photo" in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*http://link.com/photo/**photo**/user?=19746912*

See the bold part. How can i look into this link and confirm it has the word "photo" in its second level as there are two photos in the link i could not use this code:

```
$('a[href*=photo]).attr('href');
```

As you can see from the above code , it looks for the link that has photo in it then get the href out of it. the problem is what if i have two links containing photo like this:

```
<a href="http://link.com/photo/photo/user?=19746912"></a>

<a href="http://link.com/photo/album/user?=19746912"></a>
```

You can see that the first level of the both links has photo word , which is not good if im using the above code. so how can i look at the links second level , which link1 is photo , link2 is album , and get the one with the second level "photo"(first link)'s href.

I am using the latest jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not do this `a[href*=photo/photo]`?

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href*=photo/photo]

Comment: Put quotes `a[href*="photo/photo"]`

Answer (score 4):

Can you not do this:

```
$('a[href*="photo/photo"]').attr("href")
```

Or if you want to do something more complicated you can test the href using a regex:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return /\/photo\/[^\/]+$/.test(this.href);
});
```

(The regex I've included for demonstration purposes matches "/photo/" followed by one or more non-slash characters at the end of the string, so it will match your first anchor but not the second.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XAnAq/1/

Comment: just tested , firebug gave me this error " Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href*=photo/photo]"

Comment: It should work *if you use the quotation marks around the string*...otherwise try escaping with double backslash: `$('a[href*="photo\\/photo"]').attr("href")`

Comment: The code shown in my answer (_with_ the inner double quotes) worked fine when I tried it in FireFox. I didn't need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: +1 yeah your code works, I think he tried without the inner quotes